# Complex LINQ query with complex where clause

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

First of all, sorry if the name of this problem is not descriptive enough. I wasn't sure what to name it. I have two tables,

```
Games
int GameId,
int HomeTeamId,
string HomeTeamName,
int HomeTeamScore,
int AwayTeamId,
int AwayTeamScore,
string AwayTeamName
```

and

```
PlayersInGame
int GameId,
int PlayerId,
string PlayerName,
string TeamName,
int TeamId
```

What I want to do is query these two tables resulting in the following

```
ViewModel
string PlayerName,
string Teams,
int GameCount,
int NumberOfWins
```

My problem is that I'm querying games from many years so a player can have played for multiple teams in which case I want it to appear like this

```
Team1/Team2/...
```

Where the team names are separated with `/`.
Another problem is that I want to get total number of games that the player has participated in but also figure out his win record. The only way to figure out his win record is by comparing HomeTeamScore with AwayTeamScore and check Player's TeamId with winning team id.

I'm wondering what is the best approach here? I doubt there's a way to do this with a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming (by looking at `PlayerId`) you also have a `Player` class/table which you didn't specify.

Let's start by getting all the players:

```
IEnumerable<Player> players = _db.Players;
```

We need to map each player to a `ViewModel`, so we are going to use [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> models = players.Select(p => new ViewModel());
```

But these `ViewModel` instances are just empty, we need to fill in the appropiate data, let's start by specifying the easiest one, the player's name:

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> models = players.Select(p => new ViewModel()
{
    PlayerName = p.PlayerName
});
```

Next, we need to fetch all the teams that the player took part of. For this, we'll query the `PlayersInGame` table and use a [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) to filter out by the player's ID. We'll also map each result to a `TeamName` and format it.

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> models = players.Select(p => new ViewModel()
{
    PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
    Teams = String.Join("/", _db.PlayersInGame.Where(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.PlayerId).Select(pg => pg.TeamName))
});
```

Now we need to calculate the game count, we're again going to read `PlayersInGame` but now we're going to use the [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> models = players.Select(p => new ViewModel()
{
    PlayerName = p.Name,
    Teams = String.Join("/", _db.PlayersInGame.Where(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.Id).Select(pg => pg.TeamName)),
    GameCount = _db.PlayersInGame.Count(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.Id)
});
```

Now, for the final part, we need to count how many times the player won so we just need to query the player's games and then count how many he/she won. The trickiest part is probably determining if the player is on the Home team or on the Away team.

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> models = players.Select(p => new ViewModel()
{
    PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
    Teams = String.Join("/", _db.PlayersInGame.Where(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.PlayerId).Select(pg => pg.TeamName)),
    GameCount = _db.PlayersInGame.Count(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.PlayerId),
    NumberOfWins = _db.PlayersInGame.Where(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.PlayerId).Count(pg =>
    {
        Game g = _db.Games.Single(g => g.GameId == pg.GameId);
        bool isHome = g.HomeTeamId == pg.TeamId;
        return isHome ? (g.HomeTeamScore > g.AwayTeamScore) : (g.AwayTeamScore > g.HomeTeamScore);
    })
});
```

---

Final result:

```
IEnumerable<ViewModel> models = _db.Players.Select(p => new ViewModel()
{
    PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
    Teams = String.Join("/", _db.PlayersInGame.Where(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.PlayerId).Select(pg => pg.TeamName)),
    GameCount = _db.PlayersInGame.Count(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.PlayerId),
    NumberOfWins = _db.PlayersInGame.Where(pg => pg.PlayerId == p.PlayerId).Count(pg =>
    {
        Game game = _db.Games.Single(g => g.GameId == pg.GameId);
        bool isHome = game.HomeTeamId == pg.TeamId;
        return isHome ? (game.HomeTeamScore > game.AwayTeamScore) : (game.AwayTeamScore > game.HomeTeamScore);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very complex, try to refer to this post. So in the fields `Teams`, `GameCount`, and `NumberOfWin` I perform query again to get each value and put it in a variable result, from there you can assign it to your ViewModel class

```
var players = new List<PlayersInGame>
            {
                new PlayersInGame
                {
                    PlayerId = 1,
                    GameId = 1,
                    PlayerName = "Manu Ginobili",
                    TeamId = 1,
                    TeamName = "Spurs"
                },
                new PlayersInGame
                {
                    PlayerId = 3,
                    GameId = 1,
                    PlayerName = "Michael Jordan",
                    TeamId = 1,
                    TeamName = "Spurs"
                },
                new PlayersInGame
                {
                    PlayerId = 3,
                    GameId = 2,
                    PlayerName = "Michael Jordan",
                    TeamId = 3,
                    TeamName = "Bulls"
                },
                new PlayersInGame
                {
                    PlayerId = 2,
                    GameId = 1,
                    PlayerName = "James Harden",
                    TeamId = 2,
                    TeamName = "Rockets"
                }
            };

            var games = new List<Games>
            {
                new Games
                {
                    GameId = 1,
                    AwayTeamId = 2,
                    AwayTeamName = "Rockets",
                    AwayTeamScore = 107,
                    HomeTeamId = 1,
                    HomeTeamName = "Spurs",
                    HomeTeamScore = 110
                },
                new Games
                {
                    GameId = 2,
                    AwayTeamId = 2,
                    AwayTeamName = "Rockets",
                    AwayTeamScore = 107,
                    HomeTeamId = 3,
                    HomeTeamName = "Bulls",
                    HomeTeamScore = 110
                }
            };

            /*
           string PlayerName,
           string Teams,
           int GameCount,
           int NumberOfWins*/

            var result = (from g in games
                          join p in players on g.GameId equals p.GameId
                          select new
                          {
                              PlayerNAme = p.PlayerName,
                              Teams = string.Join(",", players.Where(x => x.PlayerName == p.PlayerName).Select( m=> new { m.TeamName })),
                              GameCount = players.Count(x => x.PlayerName == p.PlayerName),
                              NumberOfWins = games.Count(m => ((players.Where(x => x.PlayerName == p.PlayerName).Select(x => x.TeamId)).Contains(m.AwayTeamId) && m.AwayTeamScore > m.HomeTeamScore) || ((players.Where(x => x.PlayerName == p.PlayerName).Select(x => x.TeamId)).Contains(m.HomeTeamId) && m.HomeTeamScore > m.AwayTeamScore))
                          }
                          ).Distinct();
```

[image]